# How to use environment variables of a project in the java library?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, kubernetes

I've created a plain java-maven library which can be used by other projects. In my library, I need to use few variables from env vars like `System.getenv("ABC")`. The project using this library will define these env vars and I want my library to use them. Project will be containerized i.e. it'll define these envs in its deployment file directly or in config-map. Kindly let me know how that can be done?

PS: If any config reqd, kindly suggest on library side but no change on project side.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. With `System.getenv("ABC")` you can read environment variables, no matter _how_ they were defined.

Comment: Consider moving from sysenv to another way of config:

Dockerfile

    ENV ABC=100

application.properties

    abc=${ABC}

prod-deploy.yaml

    ... env:
     - name: ABC
       value: 101

test-deploy.yaml

    102 for example

java:

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
    ...
    @Value("${abc:103}")
    private int abc;